# SQL Server 2019 Log shipping standby Server stops responding and has a big "Index Searches/Sec" and "Locks" surge (running queries at 0)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, wait-types

We have 10 SQL Server 2019 production servers all configured the same way. We do log shipping (via scripts, not built-in SQL), to warm standby servers.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64)   May 29 2022 15:55:47   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )
```

One of our warm standby servers has stopped responding last night from 00h40 until the IT restarted it at 1h55.

I can see in the log of the standby server that the system health extended event has stopped at 00h39 and only resumed at 1h55.

[image: Extended Events system health]

When I look into our monitoring system, the only weird thing I'm finding, is that the perfmon "SQLServer: Access Methods: Index Searches/Sec" has spiked from 00h41 to 1h33. After that, the server was completely unresponsive (Windows had basically stopped SQL) and the IT team eventually got an alert, and proceeded to reboot the server at 1h53 (where the line cuts in the graph).

Note: the "Locks: Lock Requests/Sec" shows the exact same pattern than the Index searches

[image: Index Searches]

At the same time, Batch Requests/Sec is almost 0.

[image: Batch Requests]

What I do find weird, is that nothing is happening on this server, as it is a standby server. No queries run on it. The only thing happening, is that we sync the backups from the production servers, leaving the databases in RECOVERY, waiting for a failover in case the prod servers fails.

At 00h40, only standard log backups were being restored on the standby server. (The daily differential backups were not yet taken on the prod server.)

1. How can I have a spike in "Index Searches/Sec" and "Locks: Lock Requests/Sec" on a standby server where nothing happens?
2. Have you ever seen something similar?